# Redux-form loading indicator while auto saving

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am working on a react app that similar minimal version of google docs. I am using a redux form with two fields `title` and `content` and also doing auto-submitting data on a change to inputs.

[image: Google Docs Auto Saving]

How do I implement a feature that showing `Saving` while typing and `Saved` when done submitting?

```
// file: AutoSaveForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import _debounce from 'lodash.debounce'   

class AutoSaveForm extends Component {  
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="title" component="input" />
          <Field name="content" component="textarea" />
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
    )
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'auto_save_form',
  onChange: _debounce((values, dispatch, props, previousValues) => {
    props.submit()
  }, 800)
})(AutoSaveForm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to redux-form actions (change, blur, array changes ..etc) using redux-saga or create a custom redux middleware

redux-form exports all of its action type, you can import like this:

```
    import { actionTypes } from 'redux-form';
```

in your saga handler/middleware you can programmatically submit the form by dispatching [submit action](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/)

For Saving and Save status you can use [isSubmitting, isDirty redux-form selector](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/selectors.md/)

Comment: I have all those states e.g. `dirty`, `submitting` in `this.props`. `dirty` field only changed once when initial value change. 

Can I have something like `typing` state if the user currently is typing, so I can show `saving` status else when the user stops typing, checks the `submitting` props and show 'Save` status

Comment: I can use the `onChange` event on `Field` to know if the user is typing. But how do I know if users stopped?

Comment: you don't need the `typing` state, `submitting` state means saving already, once it's saved, the `submitting` will be false then you can check `dirty` to show if it's saved or not.

Comment: Thanks :). It working the way I was expecting. 
`dirty` state was not updating on form submission. So I added this `onSubmitSuccess: (values, __, props) => props.initialize(values)`.

Comment: Can you verify this logic `submitting ? 'saved' : (dirty ? 'saving' : 'saved')`

Comment: i would do like this:`submitting ? 'saving' : (dirty ? 'saving' : 'saved')`

Comment: because the submit can fail